# Newb asks about IBOutlet

Tags: input, output, iboutlet

Why are TextField and Label both considered IBOutlet? One seems to be input the other output.

I am trying to debug an NSUnknownKeyException when XCode simulator is is starting. I am running Steve Derico's TipCalculator exercise and neither my code nor his sample code has build errors but the both report the above error during simulation.

2014-12-29 22:42:32.108 TipCalculator[14401:2353607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key calculateTapped.'

import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var billTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tipLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tipRateSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBAction func calculateTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    var userInput = billTextField.text as NSString
    var totalBill: Float = userInput.floatValue
    var index: Int = tipRateSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
    var tipRate: Float = 0.10
```

...series of if's..
        var tip: Float = totalBill * tipRate
        tipLabel.text = "$(tip)"
    }
@TimLewis  I edited to show the code

Comment: Add some code so we can help debug this error. We'll have a hard time otherwise.

Comment: @TimLewis I added code by editing the original post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: ... This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key)

Answer (score 0):

Just recreate the button and calculateTapped action and it should work! I got the same error at first and this is how I fixed it!

Good Luck